# Montar tabela com div

Tags: html, css

Galera tenho a seguinte tabela em HTML

```html
 <table style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 50px">
            <img src="https://s32.postimg.org/x1llms2ph/caixa_padrao.png">
        </td>
        <td>
            <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Texto 1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Texto 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Texto 3</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Alguém pode me ajudar a montar uma igual, porem em `DIV` e `CSS`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```css
            .container{display: block;}
            .container img{float: left;margin-top: 7px;margin-right: 10px;}
            .container p{margin: 5px 0px;}
```

```html
        <div class="container">
            <img src="https://s32.postimg.org/x1llms2ph/caixa_padrao.png">
            <p>Texto 1</p>
            <p>Texto 2</p>
            <p>Texto 3</p>
        </div>
```

Comment: ok obrigado, era isso mesmo que eu queria

Comment: como faço para a imagem ficar no topo? pois o texto1 esta no topo, a imagem não

Comment: Basta tirar a margem. Ficaria assim :  .container img{float: left;margin-top: 0px;margin-right: 10px;}

Comment: ok, deu certo aqui vlw